# How can I get the columns of both tables in a laravel eloquent model one-to-many?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

Using this simple example I can get the columns in table "comments" but I can't get the columns in table "post". I know I can use "Fluent join" but is it posible in Eloquente? Thanks!

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

 public function comments()
 {
      return $this->has_many('Comment');
 }
```

}

```
$comments = Post::find(1)->comments()->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `with()`

```
Post::with('comments')->get()
```

You will get a `comments` object with all the `post`s.

Comment: but I already have that, what I needed was the columns in post..(see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

you have to write a migration like this

```
public function up()

{
    Schema::table('comments', function($table){
        $table->foreign('post_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('post')
              ->on_delete('cascade')
              ->on_update('cascade');
    });

}
```

i believe its self explanatory

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was looking for: (sorry if my question was not clear)

```
$data = Odt::find(1);
$post_date = $data->c_date;
$comments_arr = $data->comments;
$comment1_date = $comments_arr[0]->c_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it the other way.

Your comment model:

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {

 public function post()
 {
      return $this->belongs_to('Post');
 }
```

Then in your code you would want something like.

```
$comments = Comment::with('post')->where('post_id','=',$YourPostId)->get()
```

I believe that should give you the info for a post and all it's associated comments.